# Align different height column with bottom div css

Tags: html, css

I am using css to design in my WooCommerce site. My page look like this
[image]

My code like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">Stenner Tube Assemble column.......</div>
<div class="col-md-3">Image with buy now column....</div>
<div class="col-md-3">Image with add to card column....</div>
<div class="col-md-3">videos and tags column....</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>In many industrial application ...</p>
</div>
```

I want bottom space at first three column should be filled with description which is on next row div. 
I tried with different css properties such as, position, margin, flex, padding etc, but not got result.
Is it possible in css or any other way. So extra white space covered with text.
Thanks

Comment: There is no -xs- infix in Bootstrap 4.. Are you sure you using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Try by yourself first. And show us what code didnt work so we can improve your code...not a place to put your request to do stuff this isnt marketplace

Comment: I tried with different css styles but could not get result